# phantom - can't use loop with page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using `phantom 6.0.3` to scrape a web page. Here is the initial setup:

```
(async function () {
    const instance = await phantom.create(['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--load-images=no', '--web-security=false'], {logLevel: 'error'});
    const page = await instance.createPage();
    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function (requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });

    const url = // Some url

    const status = await page.open(url);
    const content = await page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('ul > li');
    });

    const contentLength = content.length // 5

    //Code Block 2 goes here
})();
```

So far everything works fine. It was able to successfully determine that the length of the `content` is `5` (there are 5 `li` items). So what I want to do now is get the `innerText` of each of those `li` elements... and this is where I get my issue.

I've try using a `for loop` to retrieve the `innerText` of each `li` element, but it always returns `null`. Here's what I've tried:

```
//Code Block 2:
for (let i = 0; i < contentLength; i++) {
    const info = await page.evaluate(function () {
        const element = document.querySelector('ul > li');
        return element[i].innerText;
    });

    console.log(info); // this returns null 5 times
}
```

I don't know what's going on. I can give a specific index to return, such as: `return element[3].innerText`, and this will give me the correct `innerText`, but I can't get this working via `loop`

Comment: If `return element[3].innerText` works, then could you use the loop *inside* of the `page.evaluate`, rather than outside?

Comment: Unfortunately with `phantom` things like loops don't work inside `page.evaluate`. According to `phantom` docs: `The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS evaluates the function in a different context so it's not aware of the parameter `i`.

You should pass `i` to the evaluate function in order to forward it to the browser process:

```
for (let i = 0; i < contentLength; i++) {
    const info = await page.evaluate(function (index) { // notice index argument
        const element = document.querySelector('ul > li');
        return element[index].innerText;
    }, i); // notice second argument is i

    console.log(info);
}
```